# Can't figure out why my javascript isn't doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have simple_form view that users can select a leave_start and leave_end date.. I want to get the dates in between this range as well example would be leave_start = 4/1/15 leave_end = 4/5/15 and dates between would be (4/1/15, 4/2/15, 4/3/15, 4/4/15, 4/5/15) I have a on click function  but when I click the gdates text box nothing shows up and i want the dates to show up in this text field(4/1/15, 4/2/15, 4/3/15, 4/4/15, 4/5/15) any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my app.js

```
 // JavaScript include manifest for the non-angular pages
 //
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require jquery.ui.all
 //= require best_in_place
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 //= require entry



$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#gdates').click(function() {

        var start = $('#leave_start').datepicker("getDate"),
            end = $('#leave_end').datepicker("getDate"),
            currentDate = new Date(start),
            between = []
        ;

        while (currentDate <= end) {
            between.push(new Date(currentDate));
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        $('#gdate').val();
    });
  });
```

This is my entry.js that has the datepicker

```
 jQuery ->

   $('#leave_start').datepicker({minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });


   $('#leave_end').datepicker({minDate: 0, beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
```

My view

```
  =simple_form_for @entry, :url => url_for(:controller => 'entry', :action => 'create'), :method => :post do |f|

    %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
      %th.lt Leave Start:
      %td.lt= f.text_field :leave_start,  :label => false, :id => 'leave_start', :input_html => {:value => ''}
      %td.lt= f.error :leave_start, :class => 'er'

    %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
      %th.lt Leave End:
      %td.lt= f.text_field :leave_end,  :label => false, :id => 'leave_end', :input_html => {:value => ''}
      %td.lt= f.error :leave_end, :class => 'er'


    %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
      %th.lt Dates:
      %td.lt= f.text_field :all_dates, :label => false, :id => 'gdates', :input_html => {:value => ''}

    %table.table.table-bordered.table-striped{:style => 'table-layout:fixed; width:100% !important;'}
    = f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => 'btn btn-primary', :style => 'margin-left:50px;'
```

Extra in my entry model I have a method to get the amount of days between leave_start and leave_end ...Which I don't think it's causing an issue ..

Entry model

```
   def range_days
     self.range_days = only_weekdays(leave_start.to_date..(leave_end.to_date)).to_i
   end

   private

   #works with l_s to l_e to calc amount of days minus weekends...
   def only_weekdays(range)
     range.select { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday) }.size
   end
 end
```

Comment: you may want to check moment.js for easier date manipulation , setDate and get Date will work for moving the days up by one if you are working with date instances. your problem is likely with the date picker.

Comment: <input type="text" name="entry[am_pm]" label="false" input_html="{:value=&gt;&quot;&quot;}" id="gdates"> application.js: @NikosM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding comments as answer:

what output do you get? this is not correct `currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);` as it probably increments the date by one second, it is not trivial to get intermediate dates, you need to increment by one day and also check for February, end of month, leap year etc.

also you do not add anything to `$('#gdate').val();`, try `$('#gdate').val(JSON.stringify(between));`

UPDATE:

If you want to display the dates in the textbox in another format, do sth like this:

```
var formated_dates = between.reduce(function(dates, date){
    dates.push(date.toString());
    return dates;
}, []);
$('#gdate').val(formated_dates.join("\n"));
```

Comment: var b = new Date(); b.setDate(b.getDate()+1) moves b to the next day, at least in chrome

Comment: @Snowman88 do you get any javascript errors (open chrome console to check)?

Comment: @Snowman88 in my console using a test example aform part of the code, it works fine, maybe the datepicker is the problem, or the field is hidden or disabled or whatever, should post the rest code as well

Comment: I updated my question with some additional stuff ....I can't post a screen shot cause I don't have enough cred. :( @NikosM.

Comment: @Snowman88, maybe you should post a live link or a jsfiddle link with just the problematic code, this would help immensely

Comment: @NikosM. I tried it in jsfiddle and it worked... could it be something to do with simple_form?https://jsfiddle.net/TMsXM/373/

Comment: Yep I'm an idiot..... in my entry new I had the id as gdates but in my javascript i had gdate not gdates... I changed it and it worked thank you @NikosM.  $('#gdate').val(JSON.stringify(between));

Comment: also is there away to tidy this up to look a little neater  ["2015-04-20T04:00:00.000Z","2015-04-21T04:00:00 so it would look like this 20/4/15 @NikosM.

Comment: Thank you @NikosM. your awesome!!! If it's it to much to ask I don't want to be a pain, but is there anyway I could subtract weekend dates form this as well say they picked 4/10/15 til 4/13/15 how could i get this to subtract the weekend days 4/11/15 and 4/12/15 ? is that possible to do with this situation?

Comment: @Snowman88, yes but you see manipulating dates is not trvial task (that is why there are libraries around ;)). Anyway you can check each date day to see if it is Saturday or Sunday and if so do not add it (skip it). Hope it helps

Comment: @NikosM. ok i will def look into that.. one more question when you helped me change the format of the date it gave me this   Mon Apr 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) Tue Apr 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400  how can I have it just show me it like this minus the time Mon Apr 20 2015

Comment: @Snowman88, you will need a library like moment.js. i have a function that is a version of php date function which formats dates according to given format (adapted from php.js project, available on github). i think this better be a new question (you can invite me to answer if you like). too much here

Comment: @NikosM. ok here you go... >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515650/how-to-change-string-into-formated-date