# Converting a string into a formatted date

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have written JavaScript code that reads text fields named `leave_start` and `leave_end` and determines the dates that fall between them. Currently, the dates I am creating look like this:

```
Mon Apr 6 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400
```

However, I want each date to instead look like this:

```
Mon Apr 6 2015
```

As you can see, I simply want to strip off the time component. Can anyone help?

---

Framework: **Ruby on rails 4.1.8**

This is my **app.js** that looks at my two `datepicker` text fields (`leave_start` and `leave_end`).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.customSub').click(function () {

        var start = $('#leave_start').datepicker("getDate"),
            end = $('#leave_end').datepicker("getDate"),
            currentDate = new Date(start),
            between = [];

        while (currentDate <= end) {
            between.push(new Date(currentDate));
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }

        var formated_dates = between.reduce(function (dates, date) {
            dates.push(date.toString());
            return dates;
        }, []);
        $('#gdates').val(formated_dates.join("\n"));

    });
});
```

Based off the answer by @Nikos M., would this be the correct way of doing it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.customSub').click(function() {

        var start = $('#leave_start').datepicker("getDate"),
            end = $('#leave_end').datepicker("getDate"),
            currentDate = new Date(start),
            between = []
        ;

        while (currentDate <= end) {
            between.push(new Date(currentDate));
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        var date_start = new Date();
        console.log(date('Y-m-d', date_start));

        var formated_dates = between.reduce(function(dates, date){
            dates.push(date.toString());
            return dates;
        }, []);
        $('#gdates').val(formated_dates.join("\n"));

    });
  });
```

---

**Additional information**

This is my index view where I would like `full_range` to look like `Mon Apr 6 2015` instead of `Mon Apr 6 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400`. I tried using `.strftime('%m/%d/%y')` on `full_range` but it didn't work. `full_range` is `#gdates` in my JavaScript.

```
 %table.table.table-bordered.trace-table
   %tr
   -@entry.each do |e|
     %tr
       %td.trace-table.bordered.trace-table{:style => 'width:8%;'}= e.leave_start.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
       %td.trace-table.bordered.trace-table{:style => 'width:8%;'}= e.leave_end.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
       %td.trace-table.bordered.trace-table{:style => 'width:8%;'}= e.full_range
```

Finally, this is my entry table:

```
create_table "entries"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.datetime "leave_start"
  t.datetime "leave_end"
    t.string "full_range"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are varioius libraries around for manipulating dates in various formats like moment.js etc

What you need here is a function to convert the date into a given format. Javascript already has a limited such feature by using `date.toString` or `date.toDate`

PHP has a function to format [date which has been ported to javascript on php.js project (on github)](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/datetime/date.js) you can literaly use that function in your project (simply copy-paste it as it is standalone)

[PHP date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

You can literaly format the date as you need including time, year etc.. (it is not limited as the js native date methods)

reproducing code here (taken from php.js):

```
function date(format, timestamp) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/date/
  // original by: Carlos R. L. Rodrigues (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
  // original by: gettimeofday
  //    parts by: Peter-Paul Koch (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/beat.html)
  // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: MeEtc (http://yass.meetcweb.com)
  // improved by: Brad Touesnard
  // improved by: Tim Wiel
  // improved by: Bryan Elliott
  // improved by: David Randall
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Thomas Beaucourt (http://www.webapp.fr)
  // improved by: JT
  // improved by: Theriault
  // improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl)
  // improved by: Theriault
  //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //    input by: majak
  //    input by: Alex
  //    input by: Martin
  //    input by: Alex Wilson
  //    input by: Haravikk
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: majak
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: omid (http://phpjs.org/functions/380:380#comment_137122)
  // bugfixed by: Chris (http://www.devotis.nl/)
  //        note: Uses global: php_js to store the default timezone
  //        note: Although the function potentially allows timezone info (see notes), it currently does not set
  //        note: per a timezone specified by date_default_timezone_set(). Implementers might use
  //        note: this.php_js.currentTimezoneOffset and this.php_js.currentTimezoneDST set by that function
  //        note: in order to adjust the dates in this function (or our other date functions!) accordingly
  //   example 1: date('H:m:s \\m \\i\\s \\m\\o\\n\\t\\h', 1062402400);
  //   returns 1: '09:09:40 m is month'
  //   example 2: date('F j, Y, g:i a', 1062462400);
  //   returns 2: 'September 2, 2003, 2:26 am'
  //   example 3: date('Y W o', 1062462400);
  //   returns 3: '2003 36 2003'
  //   example 4: x = date('Y m d', (new Date()).getTime()/1000);
  //   example 4: (x+'').length == 10 // 2009 01 09
  //   returns 4: true
  //   example 5: date('W', 1104534000);
  //   returns 5: '53'
  //   example 6: date('B t', 1104534000);
  //   returns 6: '999 31'
  //   example 7: date('W U', 1293750000.82); // 2010-12-31
  //   returns 7: '52 1293750000'
  //   example 8: date('W', 1293836400); // 2011-01-01
  //   returns 8: '52'
  //   example 9: date('W Y-m-d', 1293974054); // 2011-01-02
  //   returns 9: '52 2011-01-02'

  var that = this;
  var jsdate, f;
  // Keep this here (works, but for code commented-out below for file size reasons)
  // var tal= [];
  var txt_words = [
    'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wednes', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Satur',
    'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
  ];
  // trailing backslash -> (dropped)
  // a backslash followed by any character (including backslash) -> the character
  // empty string -> empty string
  var formatChr = /\\?(.?)/gi;
  var formatChrCb = function (t, s) {
    return f[t] ? f[t]() : s;
  };
  var _pad = function (n, c) {
    n = String(n);
    while (n.length < c) {
      n = '0' + n;
    }
    return n;
  };
  f = {
    // Day
    d: function () {
      // Day of month w/leading 0; 01..31
      return _pad(f.j(), 2);
    },
    D: function () {
      // Shorthand day name; Mon...Sun
      return f.l()
        .slice(0, 3);
    },
    j: function () {
      // Day of month; 1..31
      return jsdate.getDate();
    },
    l: function () {
      // Full day name; Monday...Sunday
      return txt_words[f.w()] + 'day';
    },
    N: function () {
      // ISO-8601 day of week; 1[Mon]..7[Sun]
      return f.w() || 7;
    },
    S: function () {
      // Ordinal suffix for day of month; st, nd, rd, th
      var j = f.j();
      var i = j % 10;
      if (i <= 3 && parseInt((j % 100) / 10, 10) == 1) {
        i = 0;
      }
      return ['st', 'nd', 'rd'][i - 1] || 'th';
    },
    w: function () {
      // Day of week; 0[Sun]..6[Sat]
      return jsdate.getDay();
    },
    z: function () {
      // Day of year; 0..365
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), f.n() - 1, f.j());
      var b = new Date(f.Y(), 0, 1);
      return Math.round((a - b) / 864e5);
    },

    // Week
    W: function () {
      // ISO-8601 week number
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), f.n() - 1, f.j() - f.N() + 3);
      var b = new Date(a.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
      return _pad(1 + Math.round((a - b) / 864e5 / 7), 2);
    },

    // Month
    F: function () {
      // Full month name; January...December
      return txt_words[6 + f.n()];
    },
    m: function () {
      // Month w/leading 0; 01...12
      return _pad(f.n(), 2);
    },
    M: function () {
      // Shorthand month name; Jan...Dec
      return f.F()
        .slice(0, 3);
    },
    n: function () {
      // Month; 1...12
      return jsdate.getMonth() + 1;
    },
    t: function () {
      // Days in month; 28...31
      return (new Date(f.Y(), f.n(), 0))
        .getDate();
    },

    // Year
    L: function () {
      // Is leap year?; 0 or 1
      var j = f.Y();
      return j % 4 === 0 & j % 100 !== 0 | j % 400 === 0;
    },
    o: function () {
      // ISO-8601 year
      var n = f.n();
      var W = f.W();
      var Y = f.Y();
      return Y + (n === 12 && W < 9 ? 1 : n === 1 && W > 9 ? -1 : 0);
    },
    Y: function () {
      // Full year; e.g. 1980...2010
      return jsdate.getFullYear();
    },
    y: function () {
      // Last two digits of year; 00...99
      return f.Y()
        .toString()
        .slice(-2);
    },

    // Time
    a: function () {
      // am or pm
      return jsdate.getHours() > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    },
    A: function () {
      // AM or PM
      return f.a()
        .toUpperCase();
    },
    B: function () {
      // Swatch Internet time; 000..999
      var H = jsdate.getUTCHours() * 36e2;
      // Hours
      var i = jsdate.getUTCMinutes() * 60;
      // Minutes
      // Seconds
      var s = jsdate.getUTCSeconds();
      return _pad(Math.floor((H + i + s + 36e2) / 86.4) % 1e3, 3);
    },
    g: function () {
      // 12-Hours; 1..12
      return f.G() % 12 || 12;
    },
    G: function () {
      // 24-Hours; 0..23
      return jsdate.getHours();
    },
    h: function () {
      // 12-Hours w/leading 0; 01..12
      return _pad(f.g(), 2);
    },
    H: function () {
      // 24-Hours w/leading 0; 00..23
      return _pad(f.G(), 2);
    },
    i: function () {
      // Minutes w/leading 0; 00..59
      return _pad(jsdate.getMinutes(), 2);
    },
    s: function () {
      // Seconds w/leading 0; 00..59
      return _pad(jsdate.getSeconds(), 2);
    },
    u: function () {
      // Microseconds; 000000-999000
      return _pad(jsdate.getMilliseconds() * 1000, 6);
    },

    // Timezone
    e: function () {
      // Timezone identifier; e.g. Atlantic/Azores, ...
      // The following works, but requires inclusion of the very large
      // timezone_abbreviations_list() function.
      /*              return that.date_default_timezone_get();
       */
      throw 'Not supported (see source code of date() for timezone on how to add support)';
    },
    I: function () {
      // DST observed?; 0 or 1
      // Compares Jan 1 minus Jan 1 UTC to Jul 1 minus Jul 1 UTC.
      // If they are not equal, then DST is observed.
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), 0);
      // Jan 1
      var c = Date.UTC(f.Y(), 0);
      // Jan 1 UTC
      var b = new Date(f.Y(), 6);
      // Jul 1
      // Jul 1 UTC
      var d = Date.UTC(f.Y(), 6);
      return ((a - c) !== (b - d)) ? 1 : 0;
    },
    O: function () {
      // Difference to GMT in hour format; e.g. +0200
      var tzo = jsdate.getTimezoneOffset();
      var a = Math.abs(tzo);
      return (tzo > 0 ? '-' : '+') + _pad(Math.floor(a / 60) * 100 + a % 60, 4);
    },
    P: function () {
      // Difference to GMT w/colon; e.g. +02:00
      var O = f.O();
      return (O.substr(0, 3) + ':' + O.substr(3, 2));
    },
    T: function () {
      // Timezone abbreviation; e.g. EST, MDT, ...
      // The following works, but requires inclusion of the very
      // large timezone_abbreviations_list() function.
      /*              var abbr, i, os, _default;
      if (!tal.length) {
        tal = that.timezone_abbreviations_list();
      }
      if (that.php_js && that.php_js.default_timezone) {
        _default = that.php_js.default_timezone;
        for (abbr in tal) {
          for (i = 0; i < tal[abbr].length; i++) {
            if (tal[abbr][i].timezone_id === _default) {
              return abbr.toUpperCase();
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (abbr in tal) {
        for (i = 0; i < tal[abbr].length; i++) {
          os = -jsdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
          if (tal[abbr][i].offset === os) {
            return abbr.toUpperCase();
          }
        }
      }
      */
      return 'UTC';
    },
    Z: function () {
      // Timezone offset in seconds (-43200...50400)
      return -jsdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
    },

    // Full Date/Time
    c: function () {
      // ISO-8601 date.
      return 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
    },
    r: function () {
      // RFC 2822
      return 'D, d M Y H:i:s O'.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
    },
    U: function () {
      // Seconds since UNIX epoch
      return jsdate / 1000 | 0;
    }
  };
  this.date = function (format, timestamp) {
    that = this;
    jsdate = (timestamp === undefined ? new Date() : // Not provided
      (timestamp instanceof Date) ? new Date(timestamp) : // JS Date()
      new Date(timestamp * 1000) // UNIX timestamp (auto-convert to int)
    );
    return format.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
  };
  return this.date(format, timestamp);
}
```

use as such:

```
var date_start = new Date();
/* use any format you like here */
console.log(date('Y-m-d', Math.floor(date_start.getTime() / 1000)));
// or even this
console.log(date('Y-m-d', date_start));
```

output:

```
2015-05-08
```

Comment: I updated my question not sure how to format it? and if thats correct

Comment: @Snowman88, the example i provided does not include time only Y year in 4 digits, m month in 2 digits and d date in 2 digits. Check the link on PHP date format to see more options (any code character returns a format of the date, this is the rational). Then choose the format it best suits you (for example i often use the format i gave in answer)

Comment: @Snowman88, a parenthesis was missing from my examples, updated answer, please update your test case

Comment: Okay @Nikos M. I'm getting it show up in my log but, in my view it still looks like it did before. I updated my question with reformatted code based off your answer

Comment: @Snowman88 strange, can you add the output you get, or better yet isolate only the problematic code (plus the output)?

Comment: I select 4/27/15 til 4/29/15 my console log came out to this ("2015-04-08" application.js:71:0) but in my view it still came out like this Mon Apr 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) Tue Apr 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) Wed Apr 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT) @Nikos M.

Comment: @Snowman88, argghh, you did not use it in the textbox only in console.log did you add the new function, change your code to use it in the textbox as well, for example change the formatted_dates code to this: `dates.push(date('Y-m-d', the_date));` make sure to change the argument of the function as well from `date` to `the_date` so as not to conflict with the new function `date`. Hope this is clear

Answer (score 1):

to_date() public
Converts a string to a Date value.

```
> "1-1-2012".to_date   # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012
> "01/01/2012".to_date # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012
> "2012-12-13".to_date # => Thu, 13 Dec 2012
```

Source : http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date

Comment: I have multiple dates though.. @Jérémy Buttice

Answer (score 0):

d = new Date
will return << Wed Apr 08 2015 18:45:45 GMT+0530 (IST)

d.toDateString
will return << "Wed Apr 08 2015"

Answer (score 0):

try this in rails c

d = DateTime.now

d.to_date