# How to format yy-mm-dd datepicker post to php?

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I have javascript jquery-ui datepicker library based function for selecting from_date - to_date range and post to php. Format is posted to php as:

Wed May 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

How can I set format for example 2015-05-20 for datepicker post to php in my function?

```
       function updateResults() {
       $.getJSON('results.php', {
       from_date: fromDate.datepicker('getDate').toString(),
       to_date: toDate.datepicker('getDate').toString()
       }, function(data,status, xhr) {

       $.plot('#flotcontainer', data, options);
       });
       }


                            //create a couple of date textboxes
                    $.datepicker.setDefaults
                            ({
                                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', defaultDate: '-1w', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
                                    maxDate: 0, showButtonPanel: true, showWeek: true
                            });

                            var fromDate = $('#from').datepicker
                            ({
                                    onSelect: function()
                                    {
                                            var option = this.id == 'from' ? 'minDate': 'maxDate';
                                            toDate.not(this).datepicker('option', option, $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
            updateResults(); // When a new date is selected update the results

            }
                            });

                            var toDate = $('#to').datepicker
                            ({
                                    onSelect: function()
                                    {
            updateResults(); // When a new date is selected update the results


            }

                            });

                            //Set the default from and to dates.
                    fromDate.datepicker('setDate', '-1w');
                    toDate.datepicker('setDate', '+0');
                    updateResults(); // Initial call on load



              });
```

Comment: first you'd have to explain **WHICH** datepicker library you're using...

Comment: you may [find this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29515797/3591273) usefull to handle in  javascript before posting

Comment: It's jquery-ui datepicker library.

Answer (score 1):

> Format is posted to php as:
>
> Wed May 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

Make a timestamp from it first:

```
$ts = strtotime($_POST['date']);
```

> How can I set format 2015-05-20 for datepicker post to php in my function?

With the timestamp, you can use date:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", $ts);
```

Comment: I tried already with php conversion like this: $from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(preg_replace('/\s\(.*$/', '', $_POST['from_date']))); But when variable is in mysql query it is not working: $query = "SELECT date, info FROM datatbl WHERE date >= '$from_date' AND date <= '$to_date' AND name = 'somename'";

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `$.datepicker.formatDate();` to convert dates.

Example:

```
var date = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
var convertedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
```

So your function would become

```
function updateResults() {
    var from_date = fromDate.datepicker('getDate');
    var to_date = toDate.datepicker('getDate');

    from_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', from_date);
    to_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', to_date);

    $.getJSON('results.php', {
        from_date: from_date,
        to_date: to_date
    }, function (data, status, xhr) {
        $.plot('#flotcontainer', data, options);
    });
}
```

For a live example check this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quk7gw9c/1/)

**EDIT:**

Use `$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', ..);` to convert dates. I changed my answer and provided a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quk7gw9c/1/)

Comment: `yy-mm-yy`?  Methinks you have a typo.  ;)

Comment: Jup, just saw it too and changed it. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is not working. Returns blank. What about ('getDate').toString()?

Comment: I can't see why it isn't working.
I added a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quk7gw9c/) that shows it works.

**Edit**: It kept returning the old format. I made you a new [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/quk7gw9c/1/) that solves this!